# Textarea de tinymce no funciona

Tags: php, tinymce

tengo un textarea en un form que lo manejo con un control tinymce... Simplemente apliqué lo que ya hice en otro formulario y que quedó funcionando perfectamente.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#objetivo",
            language_url : '../../js/tinymce/es.js',
            remove_linebreaks : false,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists charmap print',
                'searchreplace code',
                'table contextmenu paste code pagebreak'
            ],
            toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | pagebreak',
        });
    </script>
```

DEFINO el tinymce (me lo muestra perfecto en el formulario) el formulario lo tengo definido de esta forma, es mucho mas extenso con muchos controles, pero pase a ir paso a paso, funciona todo lo anterior al textarea... es decir puedo grabar los datos, pero por alguna cuestión cuando coloco el textarea apreto el boton submit y no pasa nada... ni un solo mensaje de error... es decir NO PASA... el form es asi:

```
<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
    <label>Título del Curso de Formación:</label>
    <input id="nombre_curso" type="text" name="nombre_curso" required>

    <label>Nombre/Empresa que lo realiza:</label>
    <input id="dicta" type="text" name="dicta" required>

    <label>Lugar donde se cursa:</label>
    <input id="lugar" type="text" name="lugar" required>

    <label>Objetivos Generales:</label>
    <textarea id="objetivo" name="objetivo" required ></textarea>



    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
    <a href="formacion.php"><i class="book icon"></i>Cursos y Capacitaciones</a>
</form>
```

despues en el guardar.php tengo nada extraño... el problema es que no llega al guardar.php... y no se como salir de esta encrucijada. Probé sacarle el id al textarea para que no tome el tinymce y resulta que ahi funciona perfecto... es como que indentifique que el problema esta evidentemente en el textarea cuando le pongo el tinymce...

```
 //Si supera el captcha es porque es un humano
    $nombre = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre_curso']);
    $dicta = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['dicta']);
    $lugar = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lugar']);

    $allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img><li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del><small>';
    if($_POST['objetivo']!='') {
        $sObjetivo = strip_tags(stripslashes($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['objetivo'])),$allowedTags);
        echo $sObjetivo;
    } else {
        $sObjetivo = "";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cursos (nom_cur, dictanc, dom_cur, objetiv) VALUES('$nombre', '$dicta', '$lugar', '$sObjetivo')";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($resultado) {
        echo "todo perfecto";
    } else{
        echo "error al guardar";
    }
```

cómo me enoja que no exista una forma de detectar el error rápidamente !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le saqué el REQUIRED al textarea que tiene el tinymce y funcionó.

```
<textarea id="objetivo" name="objetivo"></textarea>
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/53844)

Comment: @toledano es una respuesta. Cuando está con problemas de texto como decir "qué pavada" lo podemos editar para removerlo.